# g++ - Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ubuntu, g++

I'm trying to make a C++ script that will run some simple Python code:

```
// t.cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('TEST PASSED')");
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Upon running `g++ t.cpp`, I get the error:

> t.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated

I've found many similar questions, all specific to an IDE or other development software, or were solved by installing `python3-dev`. The `python3-dev` package *is already installed*, and I even tried manually including the header when attempting to compile:

```
g++ t.cpp -I ~/.virtualenvs/MainEnv/include/python3.5m/Python.h
g++ t.cpp -I /usr/include/python3.5m/Python.h
```

Neither changes anything.

How can I fix this error?

UPDATE: I found that using `g++ t.cpp -I /usr/include/python3.5/` seems to include the header, but then it runs into more errors:

> t.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
>
> t.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
>
> t.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've set up a similar example [on my github](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/blob/fb112107855506c1215abe845964c7c74bafd4eb/python/libpython_ex.c#L4-L8)

`g++ t.cpp` is missing a few things:

- Tell g++ where the headers are for cpython (by `-I/path/to/headers/`)
- Tell g++ to *link* against libpython (by `-lpython3.5m`)

You can also retrieve these flags with `pkg-config`

```
$ pkg-config python-3.5 --libs --cflags
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m -lpython3.5m
```

Your commandline should look something like `g++ -I/usr/include/python3.5m t.cpp -lpython3.5m`

Comment: I mentioned under "UPDATE" that adding the `-I` flag seemed to properly include the headers, but ran into more errors. `-lpython3.5` and `-lpython3` return `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3(.5)`

Comment: Ah, on ubuntu it is `-lpython3.5m`

Comment: Of course, I was 1 letter off. Thank you so much, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

`#include <...>` is for includes that come with the compiler.
Use `#include "Python.h"` for any other includes.

Comment: Both angled brackets and quotes around `Python.h` produces the same error.

Comment: The C++ standard is very vague about the meanings of `<...>`  and `"..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to compile your code:

**mytest.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('TEST PASSED')");
    Py_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**:

```sh
$ g++ mytest.cpp `pkg-config python3-embed --libs --cflags` -o mytest
$ ./mytest
```